# partial post back not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi everyone i am using first time update panel for partial post back concept but i am not able acheive this have tried alot to to do this but every time it's comin in post back condtion on when i am debuging . here's is my can any one face that kind of problem here is my code .

i want that when ever dropdownlist index  change event fired not to fullpostback attaching my code.

aspx:-

```
asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProjectPanel" runat="server" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Projects:" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="label2"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectsDropDownList" CssClass="txt-input-class" Height="20px"
                                            Width="191px" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProjectDataSource" 
                                        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
                                        onselectedindexchanged="ProjectsDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                        AutoPostBack="true">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>      
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>


 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProjectDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer %>"
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer.ProviderName %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name], [Description], [IsActive], [CreateDate], [ModifyDate], [CreatedBy] FROM [Projects]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void ProjectsDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Project");
    }
```

Comment: The code looks right. If you use a debug point does it ever get hit?

Comment: yes every time it's lying in this condition in is post back condition means its wrong becuase i read about partial post backing that postback condition will not true if use partial but why in my condition
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Console.Write("pageLoad");
        }
}

Comment: check system date, sometimes this also causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET sets `IsPostBack` to `true` for partial postbacks (as they are still postbacks).

Check [`scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property value to detect partial postback instead of `Page.IsPostBack`.

Comment: in page load event i check if(Isasync) but geting false

Answer (score 0):

Include Script Manager in your page and mention UpdateMode

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

                 //your controls to be updated

         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i have also added script manager every thing i have done it but not working so let's check this thing updateMode

Answer (score 0):

To validate if the postback is happening as part of UpdatePanel, check the following -

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
```

Every postback whether full or partial will set the `IsPostback` property to true.